# What LotR scene shows a closeup of Gollum eating a fish?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings

I remember a scene from one of the LotR movies that shows an extreme closeup of Gollum biting into a fish. It's so zoomed in that his mouth takes up the entire frame. The scene is just a few seconds long - all he does is (slowly) bite into a raw fish. I have checked Galadriel's initial "here's what happened in The Hobbit" explanation at the beginning of the first movie, and it only has a wide shot of Gollum from a good distance away.

Comment: Not 100℅ sure but I think it's from *The Two Towers*, either in the marsh or the waterfall where they're captured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course in the **first 3 minutes of the [3rd] movie** we see the transisiton of Smeagol to Gollum, it’s bad enough to see Gollum/Smeagol’s face soaked with his drooling but the close-up shot of Gollum eating a live fish made me wana vomit –[lotrplaza.com](http://www.lotrplaza.com/archives/index.php?Archive=First%20Age&TID=145002)

In my copy RotK, this scene is at 0:5:25

Comment: That was exactly it! Watching it again, I'm remembering [how nasty it was](http://giphy.com/gifs/jpuwLPLvMGoY8).